# Default arguments in Function attribute of type

Tags: julia

This works:

```
type Dude
    say_something::Function
    # constructor
    function Dude()
        dude = new()

        dude.say_something = function(what::AbstractString)
            print(what)
        end
        return dude
    end
end

dude = Dude()
dude.say_something("hi")
```

But I want a default argument for `what`. However, this code:

```
type Dude
    say_something::Function
    # constructor
    function Dude()
        dude = new()

        dude.say_something = function(what::AbstractString="hi")
            print(what)
        end
        return dude
    end
end

dude = Dude()
dude.say_something("hello")
```

yields an error:

`ERROR: LoadError: syntax: expected "(" in function definition
 in include at ./boot.jl:261
 in include_from_node1 at ./loading.jl:304
 in process_options at ./client.jl:280
 in _start at ./client.jl:378`

Are default arguments or keyword arguments not allowed in a Function attribute of a type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here isn't that you're assigning the function to a field of a type, but rather, it's that default arguments aren't supported in anonymous functions in Julia 0.4:

```
julia> function(what=1); what; end
ERROR: syntax: expected "(" in function definition

julia> (what=1) -> what
ERROR: syntax: "what=1" is not a valid function argument name
```

This restriction is because, on Julia 0.4, anonymous functions aren't generic — you cannot add multiple methods to an anonymous function.  Default values are simply a short-cut for defining multiple methods with varying numbers of arguments. In 0.5, all functions are generic, so this should work there once it's released.

For now, you can get around this by using a named function or by simply allowing any number of arguments and filling the default in yourself. But note that storing member functions in objects like this is often a code-smell that you're trying to shoe-horn Python-like OO techniques into Julia. Julia's functions are typically defined *externally* from types and use [multiple dispatch](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/methods/#methods). It's a change in style, but I highly recommend [embracing it](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/julia-users/sb49FTWfJac/b66fdX_MAQAJ).

```
dude.say_something = function(whats::AbstractString...)
    length(whats) < 2 || error("too many arguments")
    what = isempty(whats) ? "hi" : whats[1]
    print(what)
end
```

Comment: Matt's answer came in while I was writing and testing mine on v0.4.3, for most cases, I also agree it's not necessary to do Pythonesque things like that in Julia.

Answer (score 2):

The following works, at least on v0.5:

```
julia> type Dude
           say_something::Function
           # constructor
           Dude() = new((what::AbstractString="hi")->(print(what)))
       end

julia> y = Dude()
Dude(#1)

julia> y.say_something()
hi
```

You can also (in v0.4.3) do the following:

```
julia> type Dude
           say_something::Function
           # constructor
           function Dude()
               function ss(what::AbstractString="hi")
                   print(what)
               end
               new(ss)
           end
       end

julia> y = Dude()
Dude(ss)
julia> y.say_something()
hi
```

I think the problem (in v0.4.x) is the anonymous function syntax, which has been fixed in v0.5.